# Creating a CIFS/Samba mountpoint on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, mount, samba

I have a PC that is already on a shared network. I am looking to see how to create a mountpoint for a folder in the C:\ with CIFS/Samba so that I can use it to have Linux mount to it. Is this possible to do? If so, can anyone provide a link with instructions on doing so? So for example in Linux, I would like to mount this drive:

```
C:\Users\Rye\Desktop\test1234
```

A little more about the Linux machine. This is not on a Virtual Machine. It is a physical machine right next to my desk that I can SSH into. I would like to use FSR to mount a folder in Windows to the Linux Machine.

Comment: Is the Linux machine a network computer that you want to mount this Windows folder?

Comment: No it is not. It does share the same IP range though as my Windows PC

Comment: Is it a virtual PC (the Linux) or is it a dual boot? Are you wanting to mount (and then share) a Windows folder through a Linux VM?

Comment: I am going to update my question

Comment: You could mount the Windows folder using `fstab` using its share name. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: Thats where I'm stuck on actually. I have went to the fstab file and made the edits (pointing it to my IP address) but unfortunately, it does not work (it can't recognize the folder i try to mount), So I am seeing if there is an example of mounting just one directory in C:\. Also, not that it really matters but im not using Ubuntu for this, I am using Scientific Linux

Comment: From the instructions you have to have a common user account on both machines -> share the folder on your network -> edit fstab and it should work. Also, don't point it just to your IP, you have to have it in the format `\\IP\shared_folder`. To verify the share name in Windows go to `\\IP` and it'll show your available shares

Comment: Ok maybe that's what I am stuck on then is first creating a common user account. I have never actually done this in Windows. Thanks I am going to look up instructions on doing that.